# Rails 3.2 How do I convert model.inspect into a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I'm capturing "point in time" (audit) data about certain model records using the `inspect` method to dump the state of the record to a `string`.  For example after I've stored a `User` record in the variable `a_user` I call `inspect` and store the results in a string variable `archived_user_data`:

```
1.9.3p484 :045 > archived_user_data = a_user.inspect
 => "#<User id: 17, email: \"ray.johnson@breakfs.com\", encrypted_password: \"$2a$10$v3CJZftIyDW/XZpktXXdMOuN1IxMoVmaofcIqEB6kBV....\", created_at: \"2014-04-05 21:42:09\", updated_at: \"2014-04-05 21:43:25\", account_id: 9>" 

1.9.3p484 :046 > archived_user_data
 => "#<User id: 17, email: \"ray.johnson@breakfs.com\", encrypted_password: \"$2a$10$v3CJZftIyDW/XZpktXXdMOuN1IxMoVmaofcIqEB6kBV....\", created_at: \"2014-04-05 21:42:09\", updated_at: \"2014-04-05 21:43:25\", account_id: 9>"
```

When the `archived_user_data` is retrieved sometime in the future, I need to convert it into a hash. Is there a simple way to do this?  It looks like hashes converted to strings are usually converted back using `eval`, but in this case `eval(archived_user_data)` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still free to use Marshal, fine! If not, I suggest you peel down the string to the hash part using

```
s = archived_user_data.match(/#<User (.*)>/)[1]
```

after which you can reconstruct the hash using eval

```
eval("{" + s + "}")
```

Comment: Thanks Danny!  I wasn't seeing how to do the "peel down".  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just do as below using [`attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes) :

> Returns a *hash* of *all* the *attributes* with their names as *keys* and the *values* of the attributes as values.

```
archived_user_data = a_user.attributes
```

Comment: I don't have the model a_user on which to call the attributes method - that was done years ago (using the inspect method) and stored as a string in an audit record.  All I have is a string in the format:  "#<hash_id_1: hash_value_1, hash_id_2: hash_value_2>"  I need to convert this string into a hash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Marshal to dump and store any Ruby Object.

Example:

(Using reference from @Arup's code)

```
data_hash = a_user.attributes
dump_string = Marshal.dump(data_hash)
retrieved_hash = Marshal.load(dump_string)
```

You can store dump_string in file or database or in any other storage area.

**EDIT**

Specific case:

```
2.1.0 :013 > {:a => "b"}.inspect
 => "{:a=>\"b\"}"
2.1.0 :014 > "{id: 17, email: \"ray.johnson@breakfs.com\", encrypted_password: \"$2a$10$v3CJZftIyDW/XZpktXXdMOuN1IxMoVmaofcIqEB6kBV....\", created_at: \"2014-04-05 21:42:09\", updated_at: \"2014-04-05 21:43:25\", account_id: 9}"
 => "{id: 17, email: \"ray.johnson@breakfs.com\", encrypted_password: \"$2a$10$v3CJZftIyDW/XZpktXXdMOuN1IxMoVmaofcIqEB6kBV....\", created_at: \"2014-04-05 21:42:09\", updated_at: \"2014-04-05 21:43:25\", account_id: 9}"
2.1.0 :015 > eval("{id: 17, email: \"ray.johnson@breakfs.com\", encrypted_password: \"$2a$10$v3CJZftIyDW/XZpktXXdMOuN1IxMoVmaofcIqEB6kBV....\", created_at: \"2014-04-05 21:42:09\", updated_at: \"2014-04-05 21:43:25\", account_id: 9}")
 => {:id=>17, :email=>"ray.johnson@breakfs.com", :encrypted_password=>"$2a$10$v3CJZftIyDW/XZpktXXdMOuN1IxMoVmaofcIqEB6kBV....", :created_at=>"2014-04-05 21:42:09", :updated_at=>"2014-04-05 21:43:25", :account_id=>9}
```

You need to understand that hashes when inspected and stored as string aren't of the form:

```
"#<User id: 17, email: \"ray.johnson@breakfs.com\", encrypted_password: \"$2a$10$v3CJZftIyDW/XZpktXXdMOuN1IxMoVmaofcIqEB6kBV....\", created_at: \"2014-04-05 21:42:09\", updated_at: \"2014-04-05 21:43:25\", account_id: 9>"
```

But should be of the form:

```
"{id: 17, email: \"ray.johnson@breakfs.com\", encrypted_password: \"$2a$10$v3CJZftIyDW/XZpktXXdMOuN1IxMoVmaofcIqEB6kBV....\", created_at: \"2014-04-05 21:42:09\", updated_at: \"2014-04-05 21:43:25\", account_id: 9}"
```

You can eval and get back the hash if you modify your string to the format above. Refer to my three line example above.

Comment: Can you any resource for `Marshal`?.I'm excited to see that.

Comment: I have years worth of audit records where point-in-time data was captured/dumped using the "inspect" method.  I can't go back retroactively and use "marshal".  Your statement about "hashes when inspected and stored" is incorrect.  See the results of the "inspect" method  from my IRB - when I call the inspect method, it generates its output in the format:  "#<hash_id_1: hash_value_1, hash_id_2: hash_value_2>"  I didn't invent this format - "inspect" created it.  If the string was in the normal hash format I wouldn't have needed to ask the question because "eval" would have handled it fine.

Comment: If you dump a Ruby Object which has an overridden inspect method and do an inspect, it may dump the string as you had mentioned. Ie, of the format   `"#<hash_id_1: hash_value_1, hash_id_2: hash_value_2>"`. An inspect of an activerecord model or such objects dont give you a standard hash. My comment was specifically about normal hash and to make an abnormal hash into normal and do eval on it. I did not intend nor mean to say you manually created your string.

Comment: In IRB when I run through your sequence and add the following command:  retrieved_hash[:email]   the result is nil.

Comment: You may also refer to @Danny's answer which says the same. Modify your non-standard Hash string to standard Hash string and do eval on it.

Comment: `2.1.0 :002 > t = eval("{id: 17, email: \"ray.johnson@breakfs.com\", encrypted_password: \"$2a$10$v3CJZftIyDW/XZpktXXdMOuN1IxMoVmaofcIqEB6kBV....\", created_at: \"2014-04-05 21:42:09\", updated_at: \"2014-04-05 21:43:25\", account_id: 9}")
 => {:id=>17, :email=>"ray.johnson@breakfs.com", :encrypted_password=>"$2a$10$v3CJZftIyDW/XZpktXXdMOuN1IxMoVmaofcIqEB6kBV....", :created_at=>"2014-04-05 21:42:09", :updated_at=>"2014-04-05 21:43:25", :account_id=>9}
2.1.0 :003 > t[:email]
 => "ray.johnson@breakfs.com"
`